# Redshift get details of Create or replace view query

Tags: amazon-redshift

we trigger lot of create or replace view query to redshift inorder to create views. Now we want to analyze how long each query is taking time to execute and also whether same query is taking consistently more or less time.

I'm trying to run the below query but it is not fetching any of the "Create or replace view" query we have triggered

`select database, querytxt, starttime, endtime, datediff(seconds, starttime, endtime) as duration from STL_QUERY where database = 'mydb' and  querytxt like '%CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW%' limit 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because CREATE VIEW statements are not queries.  You need to look in stl_ddltext for information about DDL statements.